# Comparing two list of dictionaries and appending a value to one list from the other

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists of dictionaries. I have to compare CodeDesc in trans, and code_desc in code_tbl, and when there is a match, add the code from code_tbl to trans.

```
trans = [{'id': 12345, 'Name': 'John Smith', 'CodeDesc': 'XYZ'},
         {'id': 67891, 'Name': 'Jane Smith', 'CodeDesc': 'ABC'}]

code_tbl = [{'code': 98, 'code_desc': 'XYZ'},
            {'code': 76, 'code_desc': 'ABC'}]
```

My intention is to have something like this:

```
trans = [{'Id': 12345, 'Name': 'John Smith', 'CodeDesc': 'XYZ', 'Code': 98},
         {'Id': 67891, 'Name': 'Jane Smith', 'CodeDesc': 'ABC', 'Code': 76}]
```

Eventually, based on conditions, data from trans is to be written to different tabs of an Excel file.

Here is the code I have for this, and I get the error 'TypeError: String indices must be integers'

```
for t in trans:
#print(t['CodeDesc'])
    for c in code_tbl:
        #print([c['code_desc'])
        if t['CodeDesc'] == c['code_desc']:
             trans.append(c['code'])
```

What am I doing wrong, and how to fix it? When I print t['CodeDesc'] and c['code_desc'] it is printing all the code descriptions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am new to python. Using XLSWRITER to write the Excelfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending to the list you're iterating over when you should be updating the matching dictionary. Use `dict.update` instead of `list.append`:

```
if t['CodeDesc'] == c['code_desc']:
    t.update(Code=c['code'])
```

```
print (trans)
[{'Code': 98, 'CodeDesc': 'XYZ', 'Name': 'John Smith', 'id': 12345},
 {'Code': 76, 'CodeDesc': 'ABC', 'Name': 'Jane Smith', 'id': 67891}]
```

---

Alternatively, you could generate a dict mapping with one pass, and then update with another pass. This should be a linear solution.

```
mapping = {c['code_desc'] : c['code'] for c in code_tbl}
for t in trans:
    t.update(Code=mapping.get(t['CodeDesc']))
```

```
print (trans)
[{'Code': 98, 'CodeDesc': 'XYZ', 'Name': 'John Smith', 'id': 12345},
 {'Code': 76, 'CodeDesc': 'ABC', 'Name': 'Jane Smith', 'id': 67891}]
```

---

Finally, if you have pandas, I'd recommend doing this with a `merge`.

```
import pandas as pd
v = (pd.DataFrame(trans)
       .merge(pd.DataFrame(code_tbl), left_on='CodeDesc', right_on='code_desc') 
       .drop('code_desc', 1))
```

```
print (v.to_dict('r'))    
[{'CodeDesc': 'XYZ', 'Name': 'John Smith', 'id': 12345, 'code': 98}, 
 {'CodeDesc': 'ABC', 'Name': 'Jane Smith', 'id': 67891, 'code': 76}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you're modifying trans as you're iterating through it. Basically you are appending `c['code']` which is an int and then your loop will try to run on that int.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case you can solve it using a one linear syntax using `list comprehension`:

```
output = [
    {
       'Id': elm.get('id'),
       'Name': elm.get('Name'),
       'CodeDesc': elm.get('CodeDesc'),
       'code': k.get('code')
    } for elm in trans for k in code_tbl if k.get('code_desc') == elm.get('CodeDesc')
]

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[{'Id': 12345, 'Name': 'John Smith', 'CodeDesc': 'XYZ', 'code': 98},
 {'Id': 67891, 'Name': 'Jane Smith', 'CodeDesc': 'ABC', 'code': 76}]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
import pprint

trans = [ 
    {'id': 12345, 'Name': 'John Smith', 'CodeDesc': 'XYZ'},
    {'id': 67891, 'Name': 'Jane Smith', 'CodeDesc': 'ABC'}
]

code_tbl = [ 
    {'code': 98, 'code_desc': 'XYZ'}, {'code': 76, 'code_desc': 'ABC'}
]

for i in trans:
    for j in code_tbl:
        if i['CodeDesc'] == j['code_desc']:
            i['Code'] = j['code']

pprint.pprint(trans)
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/AtBS$ python3.7 trans_code.py 
> [{'Code': 98, 'CodeDesc': 'XYZ', 'Name': 'John Smith', 'id': 12345},
>  {'Code': 76, 'CodeDesc': 'ABC', 'Name': 'Jane Smith', 'id': 67891}]
> ```

If you look at it, `trans[0]` & `trans[1]` are both dictionaries without the `key` `Code` so you aren't looking to append you are looking to a new `key: value` to each dictionary that is in the `list` `trans`

Answer (score 0):

This is working perfect for me.

```
for i, (dict1, dict2) in enumerate(zip(trans, code_tbl)):
    if dict1['CodeDesc'] == dict2['code_desc']:
        trans[i].update({'code':dict2['code']})
```

The output is printed below:

```
print(trans)

[{'id': 12345, 'Name': 'John Smith', 'CodeDesc': 'XYZ', 'code': 98},
 {'id': 67891, 'Name': 'Jane Smith', 'CodeDesc': 'ABC', 'code': 76}]
```